# How to get the indices list of all NaN value in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Say now I have a numpy array which is defined as,

```
[[1,2,3,4],
[2,3,NaN,5],
[NaN,5,2,3]]
```

Now I want to have a list that contains all the indices of the missing values, which is `[(1,2),(2,0)]` at this case.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

[np.isnan](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) combined with [np.argwhere](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [2,3,np.nan,5],
              [np.nan,5,2,3]])
np.argwhere(np.isnan(x))
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 0]])
```

Comment: How to do the same for an array with float values ?

Comment: `argwhere` rocks! I have an ancillary question though. Given it returns a list of indices, is there any way in numpy to coalesce those indices into a minimal list of slices.  Fro example I get back `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[3,8],[4,8],[5,8]]` and would like `[[1,1:4],[3:6,8]]` primarily because my data does come in nice windows and the list of indices is huge.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to match the boolean conditions corresponding to `Nan` values of the array and `map` each outcome to generate a list of `tuples`.

```
>>>list(map(tuple, np.where(np.isnan(x))))
[(1, 2), (2, 0)]
```

Comment: I think you want `list( zip(* map( list, np.where(np.isnan(x) ) ) ) )`

Answer (score 20):

Since `x!=x` returns the same boolean array with `np.isnan(x)` (because `np.nan!=np.nan` would return `True`), you could also write:

```py
np.argwhere(x!=x)
```

However, I still recommend writing `np.argwhere(np.isnan(x))` since it is more readable. I just try to provide another way to write the code in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative is to use np.ma.masked_invalid(x). This is a simpler way if you want numpy to operate only on the valid values. For example

```
x = np.ones((2,2))
x[(0,0)] = np.nan
x = np.ma.masked_invalid(x)
np.sum(x)
```

returns 3

Comment: This does not answer to OP's question.