# Python SKLearn fit Value Error Input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, valueerror

I'm trying to fit and transform some data to use later in a model to a Classifier but it's always giving me an error and I don't understand why.
Please, can somebody help me?

```
##stores the function Pipeline with parameters decided above    
inputPipe = getPreProcPipe(normIn=normIn, pca=pca, pcaN=pcaN, whiten=whiten)
print inputPipe
print

#print devData[classTrainFeatures].values.astype('float32')

print devData[classTrainFeatures].shape
print type(devData[classTrainFeatures].values)

##fit pipeline to inputs features and types
inputPipe.fit(devData[classTrainFeatures].values.astype('float32'))

##transform inputs X
X_class = inputPipe.transform(devData[classTrainFeatures].values.astype(double))
## Output Y, i.e, 0 or 1 as it is the target
Y_class = devData['gen_target'].values.astype('int')
#print Y_class
```

Output:

```
Pipeline(memory=None,
 steps=[('pca', PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=None, random_state=None,
svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)), ('normPCA', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True))])

(32583, 2)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Error in the end of code:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h1mj.png)

[Error part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOp2g.png)

[Error part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oki2m.png)

Comment: Please add the code and the errors in clear text to make it easier to help you. Also refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you make a minimal executable example that contains the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to check the data you use ( not the code ) if it contains NaN ( not a number values ), in numpy there is the function `.isnan()` ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html ) for this [How to get the indices list of all NaN value in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754948/how-to-get-the-indices-list-of-all-nan-value-in-numpy-array)

also check for infinite values with `.isinf()`

in this kaggle kernel is example code for filling NaNs and Infs in datasets that then are used in classifiers **https://www.kaggle.com/mknorps/titanic-with-decision-trees** , also see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/25924/difference-between-interpolate-and-fillna-in-pandas?rq=1 for `interpolate()`

dropping rows that contain NaNs and Infs is done by

```
indx = devData[classTrainFeatures].index[devData[classTrainFeatures].apply(np.isnan)]
devData=devData.drop(devData.index[indx]).copy()
devData=devData.reset_index(drop=True)
```

( get index of NaN , drop all rows containing NaN using the index, reset index of dataframe )

Comment: I added the outputs bellow of those

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 possibilities for this kind of error:

1. You may have Infs in your data. In that case you may need to remove those samples. To find the Infs try. `df.index[np.isinf(df).any(1)]`
2. You may have NaNs in yout data. Check it using `df.index[np.isnan(df).any(1)]`. In that case you may replace the NaNs with the mean value of the column doing `df.fillna(df.mean()).dropna(axis=1, how='all')` .
3. Finally but most probably, is that you have a constant or almost constant feature that, once it gets normalized and divided by the standard deviation gives you NaNs or Infs. In that case you should drop that feature using [VarianceThreshold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html)

Comment: I added the outputs bellow for those