# Finding the maximum and minimum value from a df, as well as the corresponding column and row names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame similar to:

```
    a   b   c  d
a   1   2   3  4 
b   5   6   7  8
c   9   10  11 12
d   13  14  15 16
```

How do I find the maximum value in the data frame, along with its corresponding column and row name? 
For example I'd like to return: (d,d,16)
I'd also like to do the same of the minimum value, so return: (a,a,1)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What if there is more than one maximum?

Answer (score 0):

As a priori the max and the min are not unique you can play from

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(2,3))

#show max
df[df==df.max().max()]

#show min
df[df==df.min().min()]
```

Comment: df[df==df.max().max()] just returns the full data frame with all NaN values except for the max which is shown somewhere in the data frame. I am still unsure how to also get the corresponding column and row values for that max cell

Comment: You mean the row number and the column name. As I stated it's not meant to be a full answer. But from there you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/37755016/4819376

Comment: You mean the row number and the column name. As I stated it's not meant to be a full answer. But from there you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/37755016/4819376