# Boolean Indexing Comparision in NumPy not working with NaN values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

While comparing **`arr == float('nan')`**, numpy is returning False instead of True.

In **`Out[2]`**, value at index 3 should be True.

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([0, 5.3, 6, float('nan'), float('INF')])
        arr
Out[1]: array([0. , 5.3, 6. , nan, inf])

In [2]: (arr == float('nan'))
```

**Actual Output:**

```
array([False, False, False, False, False])
```

**Expected Output:**

```
array([False, False, False, True, False])
```

Comment: By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) `nan` will not compare equal with itself

Comment: because `float('nan') != float('nan')` By definition, `nan == x` is false for all `x`

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the definition, it makes sense now. [How to get the indices list of all NaN value in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754948/how-to-get-the-indices-list-of-all-nan-value-in-numpy-array) - It helped but did not completely answers the question Why '==' operator did not work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```py
np.isnan(arr)
```

**Output**:

```py
array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```