# Row and Column number of empty value present in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, null, data-wrangling

I have a data frame - the table below

| row_id | name | email | age | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com | 29 | AK |
| 2 | NaN | dany@example.com | NaN | NB |
| 3 | Elle | NaN | 32 | CA |
| 4 | Elle | NaN | 44 | NaN |

I want to have the row id and column name wherever my df is NaN/Empty in the below format

| row_id | col_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Name | NaN |
| 2 | age | NaN |
| 3 | name | NaN |
| 4 | name | NaN |
| 4 | state | NaN |

```py
import numpy as np
tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['row_id', 'col_id','Value','Gap'], dtype=object) #Creating new DF

for name, values in proc_df.iteritems():           #For loop by items
    for i,v in enumerate(values.tolist()):    #For loop on values
        if np.isnan(v):
            tmp.loc[len(tmp)] = [proc_df.at[i,'row_id'], name, v, len([v])]

tmp
```

but I am getting the below error

```py
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Please refrain from using images of data frames, instead provide reproducible data for others to play around with.

Comment: @Timo sorry I was trying but it was throwing some error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, my basic idea is to read DF by columns and if its founds `None value` `create new list` and `append` into `new df` the list such as `[2, A, NaN, 1]`.

**Note** : Dont know your logic for GAP column, so am just counting the None value in that specific cell.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['row_id', 'Col_id','Value']) #Creating new DF

for name, values in df.iteritems():           #For loop by items
    for i,v in enumerate(values.tolist()):    #For loop on values
        if pd.isna(v):
            tmp.loc[len(tmp)] = [df.at[i,'row_id'], name, v]

tmp
```

Output:

```
    row_id  Col_id  Value
0   2       name    None
1   3       email   None
2   4       email   None
3   2       age     None
4   4       sate    None
```

Comment: What if the columns have strings, numbers and special chars as there dtypes?

Comment: Doesn't matter what kind of values cell will have, its just gonna check if its empty or not. Try to apply in your code and if you still find some query, please update in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question also while I am running it and I am getting the following error 

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pd.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) and [np.argwhere](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754948/how-to-get-the-indices-list-of-all-nan-value-in-numpy-array) to get indices of null values.

This method:

- requires less manual iteration on your part
- does not require additional dependencies (pandas is a numpy wrapper)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

output_d = { # save outputs here
    "row_id":[],
    "col_id":[],
    "value":[],
}

# use .values - np.argwhere only works on numpy arrays
null_array = pd.isnull(data_df.values) 

# get an iterable of [row,col] arrays
row_col_ls = np.argwhere(null_array)

# iterate through indices and save values
for row_col_tuple in row_col_ls:

    # row_col_tuple[0] - the row
    output_d["row_id"].append(temp_df["row_id"].iloc[row_col_tuple[0]])

    # row_col_tuple[1] - the col
    output_d["col_id"].append(temp_df.columns[row_col_tuple[1]])
    
    # save the nan value from original df
    output_d["value"].append(temp_df.iloc[row_col_tuple[0],row_col_tuple[1]]) 

output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_d)

# output_df
#    row_id col_id  value
# 0       2   name    NaN
# 1       2    age    NaN
# 2       3  email    NaN
# 3       4  email    NaN
# 4       4  state    NaN
```